# Is there a way to read with library pugixml an xml containing another xml?

Tags: c++, xml, pugixml

I have been using the c++ xml parser `pugixml` for a long time. However, now I want to insert an xml inside another one.

I have tried both with `XInclude` and external entity, but on both cases the `xml_node` is not correctly read from `pugixml`. So my question is: is there any way I can include an xml file inside another and being able to read the nodes in C++ with `pugixml`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have figured out, `pugixml` doesn't support `XInclude` and `ENTITY` tags yet.

You have to code this in your Library or Application. When you get a `xml_node` named `xi:include`, use its `href` property, open that file and parse it with `pugixml`. Then replace or add it to the `xi:include` node of the base `xml_document`.

Comment: Good idea. Like a preprocessor. I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: There is an example how to do it [here](https://pugixml.org/docs/manual.html#modify.clone).